# Populating morris line graph properly inside a view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, morris.js

I have a morris line graph which looks like this in view:

```
 var lineGraph = Morris.Area({
                element: 'graph_line',
                xkey: 'y',
                ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
                labels: ['Sales'],
                fillOpacity: '0.7',
                gridTextFamily: 'mtsRegular',
                hideHover: 'auto',
                lineWidth: '1px',
                lineColors: ['#076178','#1ecee8'],
                pointFillColors: ['#fff'],
                pointStrokeColors: ['#012e42'],
                data: [
                    { y: '2014', a: 140, b: 30 },
                    { y: '2015', a: 225, b: 23 },
                    { y: '2016', a: 50, b: 18 },
                    { y: '2017', a: 75, b: 10 },
                    { y: '2018', a: 80, b: 4 },
                    { y: '2019', a: 90, b: 130 },
                    { y: '2020', a: 100, b: 98 },
                    { y: '2021', a: 115, b: 72 },
                    { y: '2022', a: 120, b: 44 },
                    { y: '2023', a: 145, b: 77 },
                    { y: '2024', a: 160, b: 256 }

                ],

         /*ViewBag.LineGraph*/
                /*    */

                resize: true
            });
```

The sample data that they provide on site looks like this:

```
{ y: '2014', a: 140, b: 30 },
{ y: '2015', a: 225, b: 23 },
{ y: '2016', a: 50, b: 18 },
{ y: '2017', a: 75, b: 10 },
{ y: '2018', a: 80, b: 4 },
{ y: '2019', a: 90, b: 130 },
{ y: '2020', a: 100, b: 98 },
{ y: '2021', a: 115, b: 72 },
{ y: '2022', a: 120, b: 44 },
{ y: '2023', a: 145, b: 77 },
{ y: '2024', a: 160, b: 256 }
```

Now inside my C# application I have a data set with following properties:

```
public Nullable<System.DateTime> DataDate { get; set; }
public Nullable<double> RevenueForDay { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> SalesForDay { get; set; }
```

And I'm trying to recreate a proper JSON string that would resemble this JSON like following:

```
 public string FormProperJson(byte type, List<SearchedUserGraphData> allData)
        {
            var finalJson = "";
            if (type == 0)
            {
                var doubleLineGraphData = allData.Where(y => y.type == type).ToList();

                for (int i = 0; i < doubleLineGraphData.Count; i++)
                {
                    finalJson += "{ y: '" + doubleLineGraphData[i].DataDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "', a: " + doubleLineGraphData[i].SalesForDay + ", b: " + doubleLineGraphData[i].RevenueForDay + "}";
                    if (i < doubleLineGraphData.Count)
                    {
                        finalJson += ",";
                    }
                }
                    // { y: '2014', a: 140, b: 30 }, this is how every line should look like...


            }
            return finalJson;
        }
```

Usage is like following:

```
  ViewBag.LineGraph = FormProperJson(0, allGraphData);
```

After every for loop iteration ends, the string looks like following:

```
"{ y: '2018-07-30', a: 33, b: 494.77},"
```

And once the complete iteration completes, the "finalJSON" string looks like following:

```
{ y: '2018-07-30', a: 33, b: 494.77},{ y: '2018-07-31', a: 23, b: 488.14},{ y: '2018-08-01', a: 16, b: 284.15},{ y: '2018-08-02', a: 17, b: 254.05},{ y: '2018-08-03', a: 18, b: 323.94},{ y: '2018-08-04', a: 20, b: 371.78},{ y: '2018-08-05', a: 21, b: 412.75},{ y: '2018-08-06', a: 15, b: 253.33},{ y: '2018-08-07', a: 15, b: 321.25},{ y: '2018-08-08', a: 31, b: 659.52},{ y: '2018-08-09', a: 13, b: 184.17},{ y: '2018-08-10', a: 17, b: 282.25},{ y: '2018-08-11', a: 15, b: 204.93},{ y: '2018-08-12', a: 22, b: 396.38},{ y: '2018-08-13', a: 22, b: 358.08},{ y: '2018-08-14', a: 25, b: 561.72},{ y: '2018-08-15', a: 20, b: 302.29},{ y: '2018-08-16', a: 21, b: 344.76},{ y: '2018-08-17', a: 32, b: 429.04},{ y: '2018-08-18', a: 32, b: 543.87},{ y: '2018-08-19', a: 24, b: 369.94},{ y: '2018-08-20', a: 18, b: 406.59},{ y: '2018-08-21', a: 16, b: 511.66},{ y: '2018-08-22', a: 12, b: 224.91},{ y: '2018-08-23', a: 14, b: 416.91},{ y: '2018-08-24', a: 20, b: 409.48},{ y: '2018-08-25', a: 16, b: 252.76},{ y: '2018-08-26', a: 13, b: 203.31},{ y: '2018-08-27', a: 9, b: 145.41},{ y: '2018-08-28', a: 4, b: 31.28},{ y: '2018-08-29', a: 9, b: 202.91}
```

But in the view, When I try to populate graph like this:

```
   var lineGraph = Morris.Area({
                    element: 'graph_line',
                    xkey: 'y',
                    ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
                    labels: ['Sales'],
                    fillOpacity: '0.7',
                    gridTextFamily: 'mtsRegular',
                    hideHover: 'auto',
                    lineWidth: '1px',
                    lineColors: ['#076178','#1ecee8'],
                    pointFillColors: ['#fff'],
                    pointStrokeColors: ['#012e42'],
                    data: [@ViewBag.LineGraph],
                    resize: true
                });
```

I get a following error in console:

```
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}'[Learn More] 
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '&'[Learn More]
```

What am I doing wrong here... It's driving me crazy... Can someone help me out?

@AlexK this is what it outputs in browser console:

```
{ y: &#39;2018-07-30&#39;, a: 33, b: 494.77},{ y: &#39;2018-07-31&#39;, a: 23, b: 488.14},{ y: &#39;2018-08-01&#39;, a: 16, b: 284.15},{ y: &#39;2018-08-02&#39;, a: 17, b: 254.05},{ y: &#39;2018-08-03&#39;, a: 18, b: 323.94},{ y: &#39;2018-08-04&#39;, a: 20, b: 371.78},{ y: &#39;2018-08-05&#39;, a: 21, b: 412.75},{ y: &#39;2018-08-06&#39;, a: 15, b: 253.33},{ y: &#39;2018-08-07&#39;, a: 15, b: 321.25},{ y: &#39;2018-08-08&#39;, a: 31, b: 659.52},{ y: &#39;2018-08-09&#39;, a: 13, b: 184.17},{ y: &#39;2018-08-10&#39;, a: 17, b: 282.25},{ y: &#39;2018-08-11&#39;, a: 15, b: 204.93},{ y: &#39;2018-08-12&#39;, a: 22, b: 396.38},{ y: &#39;2018-08-13&#39;, a: 22, b: 358.08},{ y: &#39;2018-08-14&#39;, a: 25, b: 561.72},{ y: &#39;2018-08-15&#39;, a: 20, b: 302.29},{ y: &#39;2018-08-16&#39;, a: 21, b: 344.76},{ y: &#39;2018-08-17&#39;, a: 32, b: 429.04},{ y: &#39;2018-08-18&#39;, a: 32, b: 543.87},{ y: &#39;2018-08-19&#39;, a: 24, b: 369.94},{ y: &#39;2018-08-20&#39;, a: 18, b: 406.59},{ y: &#39;2018-08-21&#39;, a: 16, b: 511.66},{ y: &#39;2018-08-22&#39;, a: 12, b: 224.91},{ y: &#39;2018-08-23&#39;, a: 14, b: 416.91},{ y: &#39;2018-08-24&#39;, a: 20, b: 409.48},{ y: &#39;2018-08-25&#39;, a: 16, b: 252.76},{ y: &#39;2018-08-26&#39;, a: 13, b: 203.31},{ y: &#39;2018-08-27&#39;, a: 9, b: 145.41},{ y: &#39;2018-08-28&#39;, a: 4, b: 31.28},{ y: &#39;2018-08-29&#39;, a: 9, b: 202.91}
```

Comment: Does this work if you hard-code the data json? Can you show the rendered output as seen by the browser?

Comment: @AlexK. yes, one moment

Comment: @AlexK. it looks like it adds some apersand signs ... :/

Comment: Anyone guys ? =)

Comment: `@Html.Raw(ViewBag.LineGraph)` ?

Comment: @AlexK. one sec trying now

Comment: @AlexK. works! If you wanna post the answer so I can accept it... just for the sake of others if someone runs onto a same issue...